# httphostconnectexception connection refused

Tags: android, exception, http-get, http-host

I know there are lots of questions about this matter but I just could not find an answer to this one in specific. I am trying to access

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://10.0.2.2:8000/timecode");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I am NOT testing on my emulator, Im testing with my real android device. Ive tried 127.0.0.1, Ive tried with my external ip

```
http://externalip:8000/timecode
```

Ive tried with 192.168...and still got the same Exception.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: i have the same problem. did u endup fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is forgetting permissions. Did you add necessary permission on your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, don't forget to disable firewall.

Comment: Try using emulator. If it doesn't create a problem, we can decrease the number of possible error reasons.

Comment: When I use the emulator it gives another exception: ClientProtocolException (or to be more specific, org.apache.client.CLIENTPROTOCOLEXCEPTION